Reducing ringing artifacts during numerical differentiation of depth image
I need to obtain a normal map from dense depth image. Naive differentiation results in serious ringing artifacts near the sharp edges. I have tried using a Sobel filter instead, but it does not really help. Smoothing the original depth map helps, but it obviously is not ideal Could someone more knowledgeable than myself point me towards best practices in this matter?

Is it a static or dynamic problem? I.e. do you have time-sequences of depth maps? If yes, provided you can establish point correspondences over time, smoothing over both time and space is the way to to - and PCA is a very efficient way to do it.
Do you have a surface model for the depth map (i.e. a prior) that can be represented as a mesh or collection of meshes?
I have successfully used in the past a method whereby a mesh is fit to the depth data first, and then the normals are computed from it - usually followed by a light round of smoothing.

Thank you for great suggestions!
Unfortunately, I have neither time series, nor a useful prior. I am getting the depth maps from the neural monocular depth estimation pipeline, and I need to obtain the best normal maps I can get from single image.

Afraid an algorithm (even if "neural") is not a substitute for understanding your own problem - which is what having useful priors means.
